# I can't get my javascript function to work?

Tags: php, javascript, short

I can't get the function to run `onClick`

my problem is I can't get `like_add` to work, or it's the `onclick` that doesn't work, I don't know thats why I need help.

It works if I alert data but I need it to make the  = .text(data)

TEST.php

```
<?php
//int
include '../scripts/connect_to_mysql.php';
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_id'] = '3';

//articles
function get_post() {
    $posts = array();

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `post`");
    while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) !== false) {
        $posts[] = array(
            'post_id' => $row['id'],
            'post_body' => $row['post_body'],
            'likes' => $row['likes']
        );
    }
    return $posts;
}

?>

<!doctype html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function like_add(post_id) {
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax/like_add.php",
                data: "post_id=" + post_id,
                success: 
                    function vote_get(post_id) {

                        $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "ajax/like_get.php",
                                    data: "post_id=" + post_id,
                                    success: function(data) { alert(data);  },
                                    error: function(msg){
                                        alert(msg);
                                      }             
                        });
                    },
                error: function(msg){
                    alert(msg);
                }
            });
}



</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $posts = get_post();
    if (count($posts) == 0) {
        echo 'Sorry, there are no posts.';
    } else {
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($posts as $post) {
            echo '<li><p>', $post['post_body'] ,'</p><p><a href="#" onclick="like_add('.$post['post_id'].')">Like</a>&nbsp;<span id="post_'. $post['post_id'].'_likes">', $post['likes'] ,'</span> people like this</p></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';

    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What the console says for you ? !
Because I think your code have some bugs

Comment: Start by checking whether all your output is as expected, and cut down code until you get something to work. As soon as just something works as expect, add a little code and see if it still works.

Comment: You should avoid `document.write` once the page has loaded - if you're just debugging use an `alert()` or `console.log()`. The version of `like_add()` in your big block of coding is calling "like_get.php" but you've also shown code for like_add.php so it might be calling the wrong thing. Also it tests for a return value of "success" but your like_add.php is returning "works".

Comment: When I click the link nothing happens, I have tried cutting down on the code, I will try again

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function like_add(post_id) {
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax/like_add.php",
                data: "post_id=" + post_id,
                success: function(post_id){
               vote_get(post_id);
               },

                error: function(msg){
                    alert(msg);
                }
            });
}
function vote_get(post_id) {

                        $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "ajax/like_get.php",
                                    data: "post_id=" + post_id,
                                    success: function(data) { $('#post_'+post_id+'_likes').text(data);  },
                                    error: function(msg){
                                        alert(msg);
                                      }             
                        });
                    }


</script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I really thought that would work it didn't, it's like my code can't find the like_add function

Comment: add an alert before the $.ajax call like so  `alert('function found!');` , this tell you if it can find the function

Comment: try removing the `;`, also the `return false;` from the onclick

Comment: I found out it works if I don't add the function like_get, is there a way that I can get it to work with that function included??

Comment: spotted a little syntax problem in your code: `onclick="like_add(', $post['post_id'] ,');"` should be: `onclick="like_add('.$post['post_id'].')"`

Comment: it still only works if I don't add the like_get, which I need

Comment: oh sorry it is actually function get

Comment: it works if function get isn't in the same script tags and if like_add doesn't call it

Comment: rebuild the function get, like you did with function like_add but change the success function to `success: function(data) {
            $('#post_'+post_id+'_likes').text(data);
        }
`

Comment: okay that worked but only if the success is an alert, I need the success: to make the .text(data) the value of post_'. $post['post_id'].'_likes   (right now it shows the mysql table data for post likes but I need it to show the .text(data) after it has been clicked

Comment: yeah for some reason it still only works if I alert data, it won't change my like count, and the vote_get function has to be in the success: of function like_add